# Test Manager_Blank screen after resuming paused test case

Tags: mtm

Test Manager_Blank screen after resuming paused test case.

When run a test case and if  we pause the test case and come out. If we try to resume the same paused test case  after some time. The test steps,screenshots all disappears and a complete blank screen shows with only one field “End Test”.

We observed the same issue in versions 2013 and 2015

Comment: Should I assume this is a manual test case? When you say "come out" does it mean close MTM? If possible do share a screenshot

Comment: My Procedure:

      Created a new test case .Run the test case and Add screenshots . Pause the test case and click on the save and close button .
      Now we run another test case add some screenshot Pause that tetscase , save and close it.
      Navigate to some other test case . The time spent is likle 3 to 4 minutes , when I come again to the first test case and click on resume  button , the test runner shows blank space.
      All the screenshot , test step information disappears.
Could you please guide me on this.